# PostgreSQL - Select all records from table knowing records id from another and display additional columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

At the beggining I'd like to say that I'm not sure about the topic's name so if anyone have suggestion to improve it, please type your suggestions.

Here are my SQL queries to create a DB's structure exactly as mine:

```
CREATE TABLE display_campaign (
    files_id integer[] DEFAULT '{-1}' NOT NULL,
    campaign_id integer NOT NULL,
    files_display_length integer[] DEFAULT '{-1}' NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE display_files (
    file_id integer NOT NULL,
    files_source text NOT NULL,
    files_display_name text NOT NULL
)
```

I've created a query that selects for me files from "display_files" table based on "files_id" FROM "display_campaign" based on "campaign_id"

```
SELECT * FROM "display_files" WHERE array["file_id"] && ANY( SELECT "files_id" FROM "display_campaigns" WHERE "campaign_id" = '1')
```

Example result table looks like

```
file_id |   file_source   | file_display_name
--------+-----------------+------------------
       1| {PLAYLIST}/1.mp4|              ADV1
       3| {PLAYLIST}/2.mp4|              ADV2
```

I'd like that to be like that:

```
file_id |   file_source   | file_display_name|file_display_length
--------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------
       1| {PLAYLIST}/1.mp4|              ADV1|              10000
       3| {PLAYLIST}/2.mp4|              ADV2|              17000
```

Any suggestions?

@Edit:
files_id and files_display_length indexes are the same. It means that files_display_length[0] is property for files_id[0] etc.

Comment: Is there a reason you use an array of file_ids inside `display_campaign` instead of each file being associated to its campaign? Would make querying and the structure easier and less error prone IMO. This looks somehow like over-complicating things without us knowing the reasoning behind the structure.

Comment: Each campaign has got few files to display. That's the reason why it's an array.

Comment: I see, still, the more common many-to-many table approach looks like a better solution to the problem and would produce a nicer, perhaps more efficient query.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join these tables. Is display_campaign.files_id equal to display_files.file_id?

```
SELECT df.*, files_display_length FROM display_files df join 
display_campaign dc on df.file_id = dc.files_id 
WHERE dc.campaign_id = '1'
```

Comment: The error message is: 

    ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer = integer[]
    LINE 2: display_campaigns dc on df.file_id = dc.files_id 
                                               ^
    HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.`

As you can see in strucure display_campaign.files_id contains array of integers

Comment: Since I can't edit my previous comment I've managed to do "half-solution"
`SELECT df.*, files_display_length FROM display_files df join 
display_campaigns dc on array[df.file_id] && dc.files_id
WHERE dc.campaign_id = '3'` but it displays array in file_display_length column which I wanted to avoid as u can see in example

Comment: try casting dc.campaign_id as a text in the where clause - WHERE dc.campaign_id::text = '1', or perhaps make the  '1' an integer. where dc.campaign_id = 1

Comment: @selfbusser none of your solution works. Have you ever tried them?